# Broken English on StackOverflow

Tags: support, specific-question, non-english-speakers

I am writing here to discuss [this inquiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822581/what-c-library-for-http-client) on the primary Stack Overflow Internet web site.

The current text of said query reads as follows:

> I'm looking for c++ library implementing HTTP client.
>   It should handle cookies as well.
>   What would you propose?
>   Thank you in advance for your time.

I am offended at the quality of grammar, punctuation and spelling demonstrated in that question; and hereby respectfully request that one of the Stack Overflow editors please rewrite it into proper English.

Comment: Actually that one is pretty good.  I've seen MUCH worse.  This at least, you can tell what he needed.

Comment: I edited it slightly, but as @CRoss notes, it wasn't all that bad.

Comment: @John Rudy (or is the ghost pirate here to stay?): You're getting there, but it still lacks a little bit of random's poetic irony ;)

Comment: I edited your misspelled tag, which offended me

Comment: @Juan: ahahahah, you made my day

Comment: @zombies Please tell us your SO account so we can examine the quality of your prose. I hope that you will not be encouraged to post something on MSO every time you encounter a post/poster whose English is not up to your standards. *re-write that crap*? Give me a break.

Comment: People should be expected to take the time to try and write quality questions. People like the one in the example routinely write garbage and rely on others to fix it. They are also the first to complain when they feel they have been wronged.

Comment: @Geoffrey Chetwood I agree with you on the responsibilities of posters. If others feel like improving the question, they will do it. If they don't, they won't. I am not sure how demanding a 're-write of this crap' on MSO fits in with any of this, however.

Comment: Seriously, the question asker wrote better English than thousands of native English speakers, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Geoffrey Chetwood and rolling back to the version before @Shog9 improved the post is bordering on vandalism.

Comment: @Sinan: Why do you care? Why do defensive about broken English and crap questions?

Comment: @Sinan: So you do want the question edited then? Make up your mind.

Comment: The ghost pirate shall depart soon; Elaine doesn't seem to be on this island.

Comment: @jjnguy: Not that there is anything wrong with that...

Comment: @Geoffrey Chetwood The wording and grammar of the question could be improved upon: @Shog9 did so. You went ahead and undid the improvements. That was wrong. Plus, @zombies' reaction to what is basically an understandable question is over the top and rude. And what the heck does <kbd>not-english-speakers</kbd> mean? Finally, if everyone posts an angry question on MSO if every time she encounters a question with bad grammar/formatting, MSO will become unusable.

Comment: @Sinan: And posting angry comments to those questions is helping things?

Comment: @Geoffrey Chetwood *Why do defensive ...*? **Really?**

Comment: @Sinan: Exactly. Now go post a meta question about it. You are all riled up, you might as well.

Answer (score 25):

You must be new here. That's very good English, especially compared to some.

Answer (score 10):

English isn't my first language either. I really can't see what is wrong with this question. I understand perfectly well what he or she is asking for. Therefore I assume that you can understand the question as well. Relax and cut us non-native speakers some slack.

On a side note:

"re-write that crap" isn't the nicest English either and there is no need to hyphenate the word "rewrite".

Comment: @Lucas: I fixed that for you. :)

Comment: @G.P.: I like it!

Comment: That question is missing articles (typical of users from areas where their native language does not have them, e.g. Russia and India).

Answer (score 5):

You're right, that's much too well-written to be broken.  Surely it can't be too hard to break?

```
We searching C++ for to plow HTTP defendent.
Must also bake chocolate chip.
Can you do me?

Thankee.
```

Howzat?

Comment: Almost, but I would have changed "What would you propose?" to "Would you propose to me?"

Comment: hahahaha.  there, is that better?  (not sure i intended to break it *that* much....)